# Python check if textbox is not filled

Tags: python, tkinter

Currently I'm using Python tkinter to build a GUI that require user to enter the detail into the textbox(txt3)

How do I validate if the textbox is entered. If not entered, should
show message "please enter textbox" . If entered, it will go through
SaveInDB() to save in database.

```
def SaveInDB():
    subID=(txt3.get())
    if not (subID is None):
        ...my code here to save to db
    else:
        res = "Please enter textbox"
        message.configure(text= res)`

txt3 = tk.Entry(window,width=20)
txt3.place(x=1100, y=200)

saveBtn = tk.Button(window, text="Save", command=SaveInDB ,width=20 )
saveBtn .place(x=900, y=300)
```

This code above does not work for me..Please help

Comment: Your code is not clear for me but just checking whether "txt3" is None, is not good method because you wouldn't consider white spaces or unexpected inputs if it is important.

Comment: @madogan which method do you prefer in order to consider in whitespaces because I want to make the textbox compulsory to be entered

Comment: @madogan I had already update my code with textbox and button, please help to check what should I do in order to validate the textbox

Comment: You can use strip() method for this as @Bitto-Bennichan

Comment: @madogan thank you so much I finally got it worked! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the entry has any value and if not use `showinfo` to display a popup message. If you don't want a popup you can simply set the focus like `entry.focus()` or highlight the background with a different color. A minimal example of what you are trying to accomplish.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

def onclick():
    if entry.get().strip():
        print("Done")
    else:
        showinfo("Window", "Please enter data!")
        #or either of the two below
        #entry.configure(highlightbackground="red")
        #entry.focus()

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
tk.Button(root, text='Save', command=onclick).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Pop up version

[image]

Focus version

[image]

Background color version

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help , finally it's working as I wanted :)